# Only Post author can reply to the post comment

Tags: php, wordpress

I want only post author can reply on the post comment . Now the login user can reply the comment but i have to restrict it to only post author. How I do this?
Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First you need to customize wp_list_comments() html out put

https://digwp.com/2010/02/custom-comments-html-output/
http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/customising-wp_list_comments/

And in the following location check if get_current_user_id() is equal to the_author_ID() and show the html output:

```
<div class="reply">
            <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: you are welcome i will appreciate if you mark as best answer